# How to run code to automate email template?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to fill placeholder text in an Outlook email.

I started with a simplified version of the code at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2021/04/21/outlook-email-templates-fillable-fields-dropdown/.
When I hit "run" it prompts me with the "Macro Name" dialog box.
If I type a name and hit "Create", it creates a new, blank module with no association to the code.

How can I get the code to run from the "ThisOutlookSession"?

My goal is to run this macro with a specific email template I created, "NewOrderNotification", to facilitate filling in standard data.

```vb
Private WithEvents m_Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents m_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
  
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub
  
Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
   'Handle emails only
  Set m_Inspector = Inspector
End If
End Sub
  
Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
  
Dim Item As MailItem
Dim Value As String
  
If TypeOf m_Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
Set mail = m_Inspector.CurrentItem
  
'Identify the message subject
If mail.Subject = "New SO XXXXX for Quote XXXXXX / [CUSTOMER] - [CITY, STATE]" Then
     
'Check message format
If mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain Then

'--------
'Replace [_SO] with the entered value
If InStr(mail.Body, "[_SO]") > 0 Then
    Value = InputBox("Enter the new sales order #")
         
If Value <> "" Then
    mail.Body = Replace(mail.Body, "[_SO]", Value)
End If
End If
'---------
         
'Repeat the code block above for the other fields in the email

Set mail = Nothing
  
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This macro seems designed to run automatically, not to be run manually.  Your posted code is missing a global `m_Inspectors` variable - did you leave that out?

Comment: Okay. Thank you Tim. In fact I noticed that after I shut down outlook and reopened it, it seemed to want to run my code upon simply opening outlook, which is not what I want to do. To answer your question, yes, I inadverntently left out the m_Inspectors variable from the forum post, but it is in my code. I have an email template called "NewOrderNotification". I want this code to just run manually, specific for that template - via a button click in the ribbon. Any advice on how to write the code for that purpose, instead of it trying to run upon generically starting outlook?

Answer (score 0):

This should be close:

```vb
Sub ReplaceMailText()
    
    Dim mail As MailItem, oInspector As Inspector, txt
    Set oInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    
    If oInspector Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No active inspector"
    Else
        Set mail = oInspector.CurrentItem
        If Not mail.Sent Then
        
            'Check message format
            If mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain Then
                If InStr(mail.Body, "[_SO]") > 0 Then
                    txt = InputBox("Enter the new sales order #")
                         
                    If txt <> "" Then
                        mail.Body = Replace(mail.Body, "[_SO]", txt)
                    End If
                End If
            End If 'plain text
        
        End If     'not Sent
    End If         'have mail
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works, but only if my email is in Plain Text format. Any way to get it to work with HTML format so that I can retain my desired fonts, etc?

Comment: Never mind. Looks like that was as simple as changing to "olFormatHTML" AND changing "mail.Body" to "mail.HTMLBody"

Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to check for the message body format. The `Body` will return a plain text body representation anyway:

```
  
Private Sub RunForInspector()
  Dim m_Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
  Dim Item As MailItem
  Dim Value As String
  
  Set m_Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector
  If TypeOf m_Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
    Set mail = m_Inspector.CurrentItem
  
    'Identify the message subject
    If mail.Subject = "New SO XXXXX for Quote XXXXXX / [CUSTOMER] - [CITY, STATE]" Then
     
    '--------
    'Replace [_SO] with the entered value
    If InStr(mail.Body, "[_SO]") > 0 Then
      Value = InputBox("Enter the new sales order #")
         
    If Value <> "" Then
      mail.Body = Replace(mail.Body, "[_SO]", Value)
    End If
    '---------
         
    'Repeat the code block above for the other fields in the email

    Set mail = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```

Also if you deal with a HTML-based message body and want to preserve the markup you would need to deal with `HTMLBody` property instead. The `Body` represents the plain message body.

Comment: Thank you for the additional perspective!